# Derivation of Search Gradients for Natural Evolution Strategies

Tags: integration, expected-value, log-likelihood

My question refers to chapter 2 of the Natural Evolution Strategies [paper](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume15/wierstra14a/wierstra14a.pdf). I want to understand the derivation of the search gradients.

Given z, a solution vector sampled from a probability distribution function π(z,θ). θ denotes the parameters of density π(z | θ) and f(z) denotes the fitness
function for samples z. The idea is to maximise the expected value of the fitness score of a sampled solution.

We can write the expected fitness under the search distribution as

[image]

If we apply a *probabilistic identity trick*, where we multiply our expressions by one (formed by the division of a probability density by itself), we can express the search gradients the following way:

[image]

Then obtain the estimate of the search gradient from samples z1...zλ:

[image]

Here I am failing to understand two things:

1) The step of gradient derivation where we replace the integral with the expectation E (the first question mark). From school I remember that integral can be found by summation:
[image]

With a fairly small step it gives accurate value of the integral. So for sin(x) we could calculate the integral as

```
sin(x1)*dx + sin(x2)*dx + ... sin(xN)*dx + ...
```

Similarly we could rewrite the last expression with the integral (underscored yellow) as

```
[f(z1)*∇log(p(z1))*p(z1)]*dz + [f(z2)*∇log(p(z2))*p(z2)]*dz + ... [f(zN)*∇log(p(zN))*p(zN)]*dz + ...
```

On the other hand, the expected value E[f(z) * ∇log π(z,θ)], which is said to be equal to the formula with the integral, is calculated as

```
E[f(z) * ∇log π(z,θ)] = [f(z1)*∇log p(z1)]*p(z1) + [f(z2)*∇log p(z2)]*p(z2) + ...
```

Thus, the expected value differs from the integral by the summation step (dz). Could somebody explain what I am missing?

2) The second thing which is unclear to me is the approximation of the search gradient (the second question mark in the picture). We calculate the expected value by summing up [f(zk) * ∇log π(zk,θ)] and divide it by the number of samples λ. In my understanding it makes sense only if p(zk) = 1/λ for all k samples. That means z must be uniformly distributed, however z is sampled from π(z,θ) which may not necessarily be a uniform distribution.